# Search WHERE value is present in one of the JSON array using only regular expression

Tags: json, regex, postgresql-9.2

My column looks something like this

```
"{"a1":"{\"name\":[{\"id\":32,\"addId\":[28947,33268,48148,1594,57818,57819],\"hasPhone\":true}],\"phone\":[{\"phoneId\":5,\"selectionMode\":true}],\"phoneType\":[1],\"selectionMode\":\"GROUP\"}"}"
```

It is a JSON field but we are still on postgres 9.2 so there is no JSON support for search.

I have to get all records where addId is either 28947 or 57818

Please help

Comment: That is not a valid JSON document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regular expression that matches 
`addId\":[` followed by any number of `,` and decimal digits with your magic numbers in the middle, ending in `]`.

```
SELECT regexp_matches(json_column, 'addId\\":\[[0-9,]*(28947|57818)[0-9,]*\]', 'g');
```

Tested it on your input data at [this site](https://regex101.com/). Did not test it with the actual `regexp_matches` function

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that but this 5 digit Id can also be present in other places, I wanted to search in addId array in json

Comment: alright @Pratik I edited it. Tested it on your input data at [this site](https://regex101.com/). Did not test with sql regex function